# Can I specify the border to be on the inside?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have defined a hexagon using `System.Windows.Shapes.Path`, but by applying `Stroke` to it (`SolidColorBrush`) the border goes outside and inside.

How can I make it so that the stroke is only applied on the inside of my `Path`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) dependency property : the idea is to clip the path by its own geometry like this.

```
<Path ... Clip="{Binding Data, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

You have to double the StrokeThickness, since only half of the stroke is visible.

Even if it works well in silverlight and WPF, I had some problems in the past with this code (binding Clip to a relative source) ; I solved this easily by a adding another binding or simply by assigning Clip in the code .

Edit : 
Also note, that for clipping, pathGeometry should be filled.

> The clipped area is the "outside" of the geometry. In other words, the
>   content that is shown (not clipped) is the area of the geometry that
>   would otherwise have a Fill if the geometry were used as data for a
>   Path rather than for clipping. The clipped area is any area that falls
>   outside the geometry overlay. For complex geometries, the areas that
>   are clipped or not clipped are influenced by the geometry's FillRule.

Comment: I've tried:

path.Data = pathGeometry;
path.Clip = pathGeometry; (added this)

but it states ArgumentException :-(

Comment: for clipping, pathGeometry should be filled